# Why need 2NF?

Tags: database

Just wondering sometime the 2NF may not be necessary.

```
Option 1. ORDERS {orderId (pk), custId (fk), total, date, status, ...}
   PARTS {orderId (pk), partsId (pk), qty, unitPrice, description, ...}

Option 2. ORDERS {orderId (pk), custId, total, date, status, ...}
   ORDER_PARTS {orderId (pk)(fk), partsId (pk)(fk), qty, ...}
   PARTS {partsId (pk), unitPrice, description, ...}
```

Most people like Option 2, I think, because it is 2NF but I think Option 1 is better because it will be simpler and faster when we query them. Why we need 2NF in cases like this?

Comment: Seriously, I don't think you should have the "DBA" in your user name if you're asking this question. Unless you mean you expect to be a DBA 5 years from now :-)

Comment: yes, 5 years later. not now. now just start to learn

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA Nothing to do with the question but I'm just curious whether you have became the "DBA" after 5 years? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a beginning DBA, you should be putting *everything* into third normal form. That means, every column in a row depends on:

- the key (1NF).
- the whole key (2NF).
- nothing but the key (3NF).

With experience, you can opt to revert sometimes to 2NF for various reasons (usually speed), but that's not something I'd be worrying about as a beginner.

Comment: "The key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd." :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want the 2nd normal form because with option 1, a part doesn't exist unless it belongs to an order.

Comment: You are right, but it is true sometimes. when we received a new order, some parts might be new to us and no record for them.

Answer (score 1):

In Option 1, when the user wants to change the description of a part, you will have to change it on ALL the orders associated to that part. Don't you feel the bad smell?